# Amazon ECR registry as Private registry

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-registry, amazon-ecr

Cant I use `Amazon ECR` registry the same was as I am creating `private registry`?

1. Whitelist the private registry by adding to daemon.json file and restart docker service
2. `docker push <ecr/registry/ip>/<image_name>`
3. `docker pull <ecr/registry/ip>/<image_name>`

we need to use `aws cli`, but I dont want to use the same and handle it via private registry method.
Any leads?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `aws cli`,

`aws ecr get-login --registry-ids 012345678910 023456789012`

This command will output one or more `docker login` commands for you that includes a user, a password and the specific registry urls for the registries that you requested, then you can `eval` the output or run the command(s) manually, after that you can use `docker pull` and `docker push`.

More info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login.html)